# Any way to find out which line break char(s) to use in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to parse some text into a textarea control and at the same time replace all 
 with ordinary line break chars.

I have been able to do it in windows by replacing 
 with `CR` (it didn't work with `CRLF` strangely enough, it gave me linebreak + empty space) but I'm afraid that this code won't work in Unix/Mac because they use `LF` for line break.

Is there any way to use the system default line break char in javascript? Something similar to Environment.NewLine in .Net

(I wasn't able to write backslash in this editor but I use `\r` for `CR` and `\n` for `LF`)

Edit: I should probably mention that everything works with FF, it's as always internet explorer (8) I'm having problems with.

Edit2:

I can reproduce my problem with this code. When I run it in IE8 I get "row1  row2" but when I run it in FF I get real line breaks:

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function fill() {
        var text = "row1<br /><br />row2";

        $('#fill_me').text(text.replace(/<br \/>/g, '\n'));
    }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="fill()">
    <textarea rows=10 cols=100 id="fill_me"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Your question is really confusing. "at the same time replace all 
with ordinary line break chars"...replace all what? what's your definition of "ordinary line break chars"? Moreso, sample input + expected output + actual output would be nice, and a test case would be even better.

Comment: I added some code that might help explain things. I basically want to take html formatted text and replace all <br /> with real line breaks in a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the newline character, its your use of jQuery functions.

You should be using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) for changing the `value` of a `<textarea>`.  `.text()` is for changing the textContent of nodes (like a `<div>`, etc).   Newline chars inside of `text()` will likely be converted to plain spaces...

[Demonstrated on jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/GZtmd/)

Comment: Oh man, I'm so mad at myself for missing that one :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `\n` as your linebreak character in Javascript.

For example the statement,

`document.getElementById('mytextarea').value = "This is some text.\n\nAnd here is some more."`;

adds two returns between the "This is some text." and "And here is some more." in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

Comment: I'm using (with jQuery):
 $('#text_field').text(data.replace(/<br \/>/g, '\n'));

Comment: @Irro: I'd love to see how you tried it then, because it works on all the browsers I have at my disposal. You did say you were putting the value into a `<textarea>`, did you not?

Comment: I added a small example in my original post that reproduce my problem.